# python3.6 help command dumping core when we try help(tensorflow)

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow

I am running Ubuntu Linux 18.04 on Virtual box, 
I have installed tensorflow properly in `venv` and import works fine and also
I could run some sample programs with tensorflow, but when i try `help(tf)` python prompt as show below in the logs, I am hitting coredump,

```
`(venv) shiv@shiv-vbox:~/TF$ python
 Python 3.6.7 (default, Oct 22 2018, 11:32:17) 
[GCC 8.2.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import tensorflow as tf
>>> x=0
>>> help(x)

>>> help(tf)
Segmentation fault (core dumped)`
```

Is something wrong with my installation? i tried multiple times to install to confirm some issue with install but all the time I am getting cordump when I do help(tf), any inputs on this would be helpful.

-Thank you

## update

I followed following steps to install

`shiv@shiv-vbox:~/TF$ sudo virtualenv --system-site-packages -p python3 ./venv
Already using interpreter /usr/bin/python3
Using base prefix '/usr'
New python executable in /home/shiv/TF/venv/bin/python3
Also creating executable in /home/shiv/TF/venv/bin/python
Installing setuptools, pkg_resources, pip, wheel...done.
shiv@shiv-vbox:~/TF$ source ./venv/bin/activate
(venv) shiv@shiv-vbox:~/TF$ 
(venv) shiv@shiv-vbox:~/TF$ ls
Tflow  venv
(venv) shiv@shiv-vbox:~/TF$ pip install --upgrade pip
Requirement already up-to-date: pip in ./venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages (18.1)
(venv) shiv@shiv-vbox:~/TF$ pip install tensorflow`

Comment: How did you install it? Also, have you tried running anything other than `help()`?

Comment: @IanQuah : yes, as i said other things works fine,  executed few sample python programs from tensorflow document, they work fine,  and also for others  `help()` works perfectly fine.